# multiple if loop condition and priting the output in a column

Tags: r, if-statement

I've a data set with two columns shown below:

```
 x1     | x2
ontime  |ontime
Alate   |ontime
ontime  |Blate
Alate   |Blate
```

my desired output is

```
  x12
ontime
Alate
Blate
Alate
```

I was trying to write multiple if loops:

```
 df$x12<- if(df$x1=='Alate' & df$x2=='ontime')
 {
 print('Alate')
 }else if(df$x1=='ontime' & df$x2=='Blate')
 {
 print('Blate')
 }else if(df$x1=='Alate' & df$x2=='Blate')
 {
 print('Alate')
 }else 
 print('ontime')
```

but it is not working it just prints "ontime" for all the rows with a warning:

> the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: Because `if()` is not vectorized, you can try to chain `ifelse()` or use `mapply()`

Comment: Just `do.call(pmin, df)` Will work if these are `character` vectors (i.e. `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` was specified upon creation).

Comment: @DavidArenburg, can you please explain what is "pmin" here and how it works?

Comment: I've just spotted your pattern, You want to basically sort the results alphabetically, i.e, `'Alate'` always comes first, then `'Blate'`, then `'ontime'`. Hence, I can just call `pmin` over the whole data.frame as data.frames are just lists. But that's just a trick, if you ask me, for general cases it is better to use subsets approach as introduced by @Adamm

Comment: @DavidArenburg, noted, but here the data has to be a list and this would work on any column which is a list in the data frame.

Comment: Have no idea what are you talking about, sorry. All data.frames are lists, their columns could be of any type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way with chaining `ifelse()` :

Data :

```
x1 <- c("ontime", "Alate", "ontime", "Alate")
x2 <- c("ontime", "ontime", "Blate", "Blate")
df <- data.frame(x1, x2)
> df
      x1     x2
1 ontime ontime
2  Alate ontime
3 ontime  Blate
4  Alate  Blate
```

Then you can write :

```
df$x3 <- ifelse(x1 == "Alate" & x2 == "ontime", "Alate",
                ifelse(x1 == "ontime" & x2 == "Blate", "Blate",
                       ifelse(x1 == "Alate" & x2 == "Blate", "Alate", "ontime")))

> df
      x1     x2     x3
1 ontime ontime ontime
2  Alate ontime  Alate
3 ontime  Blate  Blate
4  Alate  Blate  Alate
```

Comment: Using one `ifelse` is bad enough, using 3 nested `ifelse` is much worse and absolutely unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you all, @Mbr Mbr, thank you for the mapply option, I learnt something new and yes the if loop worked

Comment: @DavidArenburg Yeah I deleted the answer as soon as I saw my error.

Answer (score 3):

This approach is picking up [David's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45012215/multiple-if-loop-condition-and-priting-the-output-in-a-column/45012348#comment76999552_45012215) to use `pmin()` but extends it to work with arbitrary orders.

David had observed that `Alate` always comes first, then `Blate`, and finally `ontime`. However, it can't be taken for granted that the requested order is the same as the alphabetical order. But by using *ordered factors*, the approach can be extended for arbitrary orders:

```
library(data.table)
# Specify the priority
prio <- c("Alate", "Blate", "ontime")
# coerce to data.table, convert columns to ordered factors, using the same levels,
# pick the value with the higher priority (lower level number) 
data.table(DF)[, c("x1", "x2") := lapply(.SD, ordered, levels = prio)][, x12 := pmin(x1, x2)][]
```

> ```
>        x1     x2    x12
> 1: ontime ontime ontime
> 2:  Alate ontime  Alate
> 3: ontime  Blate  Blate
> 4:  Alate  Blate  Alate
> ```

This approach avoids nested `ifelse()` expressions or multiple selective updates.

#### Data

```
DF <- structure(list(x1 = c("ontime", "Alate", "ontime", "Alate"), 
x2 = c("ontime", "ontime", "Blate", "Blate")), .Names = c("x1", 
"x2"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should post your dataset example using `dput`.
As for your code, you must be aware that R is vectorized, hence the warning. The `if` statement is trying to compare just one elemet of `df$x1` with `'Alate'`, etc, but that vector has many elements. The solution is to use `ifelse`, which is vectorized.

```
dat <- read.table(text = "
x1|x2
ontime|ontime
Alate|ontime
ontime|Blate
Alate|Blate
", header = TRUE, sep = "|", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dat$x12 <- ifelse(dat$x1=='Alate' & dat$x2=='ontime', 'Alate',
    ifelse(dat$x1=='ontime' & dat$x2=='Blate', 'Blate',
    ifelse(dat$x1=='Alate' & dat$x2=='Blate', 'Alate', 'ontime')))

dat
```

Note also that I've changed the name of your data frame, since `df` already is the name of an R function.

Answer (score 1):

If statement that you want to use, works only with a logical vector of length 1. So maybe don't use if at all.

```
x12 <- df$x1=='Alate' & df$x2=='ontime'
df[x12, 'x12'] <- 'Alate'

x12 <- df$x1=='ontime' & df$x2=='Blate'
df[x12, 'x12'] <- 'Blate'

x12 <- df$x1=='Alate' & df$x2=='Blate'
df[x12, 'x12'] <- 'Alate'

df[is.na(df)] <- 'ontime'

> df
      x1     x2    x12
1 ontime ontime ontime
2  Alate ontime  Alate
3 ontime  Blate  Blate
4  Alate  Blate  Alate
```

Comment: thanks for the solve, I tried this and it works giving me "true" or "False" in the output with an error in all the top three lines:
#incorrect number of subscripts on matrix

Comment: `> typeof(dat)
[1] "list"`  What do you have?

Comment: So you have character vector, and we need data frame if you type:`x1 <- c("ontime", "Alate", "ontime", "Alate")
x2 <- c("ontime", "ontime", "Blate", "Blate")
df <- data.frame(x1, x2)` my code should work. You can also convert char vector ti list but it's a bit tricky.

Comment: copy, Also I used the same ifelse loop (by MBR MBR) for another dataframe but the output shows as double, the raw data is same for both the dataframes. Is it possible? for that reason it is giving me wrong output and the output is of logical type

Comment: when I used your code on the second data frame it giving an error  ` #arguments imply differing number of rows: 444, 453` I'm comparing the output of first data frame to a column in second data frame

Comment: Try to use others solutions. I just copy your dataset and paste it into txt file than I used `read.table`. Type of data should be data frame or list, I don't know how does your real data look like